# ffmpeg : Convert a legally purchased video on Google

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, webm, vp9

I've bought a video on the Google Play Store. I need to have it on my computer in order to edit it for a video montage. But Google says "Important: You cannot download movies and TV shows onto a PC, Mac, and other laptops or computers."

The video has a YouTube link. As I paid for it, I can watch it. I've managed to get the video part and the audio thanks to some web tools.
The video is a .webm file and the audio a .m4a file.

I can hear the audio with VLC but I can't watch the video. Even if VLC displays "21:42" for the timecode.

Here are informations for the webm file (from MediaInfo) :

```
General
Complete name                            : XXX\videoplayback.webm
Format                                   : WebM
Format version                           : Version 4 / Version 2
File size                                : 357 MiB
Duration                                 : 21 min 42 s
Overall bit rate                         : 2 301 kb/s
Writing application                      : google/video-file
Writing library                          : google/video-file

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : VP9
Codec ID                                 : V_VP9
Duration                                 : 21 min 42 s
Bit rate                                 : 2 203 kb/s
Width                                    : 854 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.224
Stream size                              : 342 MiB (96%)
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

It seems to be a good video file.

I wanted to convert it with some video converters but none of them works. So I've tried to download ffmpeg, I renamed the video to "video.webm" and tried a lot of commands. But none of them worked.

Here are informations from ffprobe command :

```
C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\ffmpeg-20200424-a501947-win64-static\bin>ffprobe -i video.webm
```

Results :

```
ffprobe version git-2020-04-24-a501947 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
  libavcodec     58. 81.100 / 58. 81.100
  libavformat    58. 42.101 / 58. 42.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 79.100 /  7. 79.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[vp9 @ 00000284720d5f40] Invalid frame marker
    Last message repeated 111 times
[vp9 @ 00000284720d5f40] Profile 4 is not yet supported
[vp9 @ 00000284720d5f40] Invalid frame marker
    Last message repeated 6 times
[matroska,webm @ 00000284720cd840] decoding for stream 0 failed
[matroska,webm @ 00000284720cd840] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: vp9 (Profile 0), none, 854x480): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'video.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : google/video-file
  Duration: 00:21:42.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2301 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), none, 854x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      enc_key_id      : [24 characters I prefer not to display]
```

If ever I initiate a conversion, I get :

```
[vp9 @ 0000019038a80980] Invalid frame marker
[vp9 @ 0000019038c0fe40] Invalid frame marker
[vp9 @ 0000019038c193c0] Invalid frame marker
[vp9 @ 0000019038c1e780] Invalid frame marker
[vp9 @ 0000019038c29100] Invalid frame marker
[vp9 @ 0000019038c324c0] Invalid frame marker
[vp9 @ 0000019038c3d480] Invalid frame marker
[vp9 @ 0000019038c47280] Invalid frame marker
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[vp9 @ 0000019038c4c080] Invalid frame marker
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[vp9 @ 0000019038a80980] Invalid frame marker
```

etc.
Then :

```
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Resource temporarily unavailable
    Last message repeated 243 times
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Resource temporarily unavailabletrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
    Last message repeated 306 times
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Resource temporarily unavailabletrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
    Last message repeated 190 times
```

I've already checked on the Internet solutions for the raised issues :

- Invalid frame marker
- unspecified pixel format
- Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

But it didn't work in my case.

Obviously, I can watch the video on YouTube when I'm logged into my purchase account. I presume they have a high level security algorithm, that's why I can't do nothing. Mayve there is something with the "enc_key_id" in the metadata, they get it and the video can only be read with it. I don't know.

I find it unacceptable not to be able to use freely my purchased videos.

Would anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does not come from the tool. I'm afraid szatmary is right, it's the AES encryption.

Answer (score 4):

The file is protected with DRM. The video is encrypted, and since the decoder doesn't know how to decrypt, The decoder sees it as corrupted.

> I find it unacceptable not to be able to use freely my purchased videos.

It doesn't matter. When you purchase something it usually comes with terms and conditions and licenses that you accept as part of the purchase. You must read those before you buy.

Comment: I see. That was my fear. Indeed, I did not take the time to read it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Out of topic: In another point of view, if you purchase audio/video from many streaming services, you only have right to use it, not to keep it, unlike CDs.